# Maven resources plugin copy file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'd like to copy eclipse.properties.ref as eclipse.properties if eclipse.properties does not exist. I'm using maven 3.2 and Java 7.

I tried the following, but not sure how to map the old file to new.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <!-- here the phase you need -->
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>/src/test/resources</outputDirectory>
        <resources>          
          <resource>
            <directory>/src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>eclipse.properties.ref</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>              
      </configuration>            
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: There is missing `</includes>` closing tag. Are you sure that this xml works?

Comment: Edited the xml.  Build runs now without error, but the file is not copied with a new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html). It seems like [`copy`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) does exactly is what you need.

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <property 
                    name="resources"
                    value="${project.basedir}/src/test/resources" />
                <copy 
                    overwrite="false"
                    file="${resources}/eclipse.properties.ref"
                    toFile="${resources}/eclipse.properties" />
            </target>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

***NOTE***

Also I'd suggest you to copy to `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}` instead of `${project.basedir}/src/test/resources` so it's will not hurt your version control system.

Comment: @Jim no problem :)